# Is there a similar English phrase for this Tamil proverb - "Lavish outside home yet starving inside of it"?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, idiom-requests

In Tamil, a south Indian language, there is a saying which roughly translates into English as:

> Lavish outside home, starving inside of it.

### Background :

This proverb has a mocking tone and indicates people who project themselves to be very rich and appear to spend lavishly on property and things, making their neighbors and the community around them envious of their stature. But in reality, whatever they are spending (or appear to spend) is because they have borrowed huge sums of money from other people and financial institutions. So much in fact that they are unable to feed their own family, probably skip a meal every day but when they step outside their home they try to appear posh and well-to-do.

Some close friends and relatives who know what's really going on with these people use this form of expression.

---

Generally, I tend to find equivalent English proverbs that have the same tonality and convey the meaning as is but this particular one has been eluding me for long. ***Any suggestions, even if they don't convey the entire meaning?***

Comment: [Keep up appearances](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+up+appearances) *- to hide your personal or financial problems from other people by continuing to live and behave in the same way that you did in the past*

Comment: @FumbleFingers -  Could you post this as an answer please? It certainly comes very close!

Comment: I think "idiomatic phrase requests" arising from "translations" are better suited to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). But if you want to copy my comment into an answer yourself, you're welcome.

Comment: "Rather steak in a chalet than gristle in a castle"

Comment: Perhaps localized to the US west, but the expression "Big hat, no cattle" seems to fit.  Though it's rather broader, applying to anyone who makes pretensions but has nothing to back them up.

Comment: I wish I knew ... then I'd know what to call all of the people driving Lincoln Navigators, Lexuses, Porche Cayennes, Hummers, etc ... that I see parked at Walmart.  (I mean ... maybe they're just really frugal rich people ... but the Walmart in Bowie, MD is just hell to get in & out of the parking lot ... you don't go there if you can avoid it, especially when there's a Target just up the road)

Comment: [*Living large*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=m7le7O8KAEwC&pg=PT95&dq=idiom+"living+large"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwithc-R4c_KAhUplYMKHcpBCsUQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=idiom%20%22living%20large%22&f=false) might be used.

Comment: One Chinese proverb is "打肿脸充胖子“, which literally means to beat up your own face and pretend to be fat. It has a proverbial meaning identical to the one in the question.

Comment: Similar idea, "The suburb was first called Bread and Lard Island around 100 years ago, as it was seen as an elegant place and when people managed to buy a house there, they couldn't afford to eat – and so survived on the basics."

Read more: http://www.nottinghampost.com/Bread-Lard-Island-boomed-care/story-15107229-detail/story.html

Comment: When I was a teenager, the people in one particularly posh new development were derisively called "cornflake eaters" because that's what they ate, according to the local grocer.   (Southern New England)

Comment: **All hat, no cattle** is the usual in AmE

Comment: a Scottish phrase for this is something like "they're just 'could-be's that 'would-be's..."

Comment: As a native tamil speaker... what's the original proverb?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - "ஊரு மெச்சும் உள்வீடு பட்டினி" is the original Tamil proverb. It has more than one interpretation as you might be aware of.

Comment: Wine taste and beer budget?  Four bold tires on your Cadillac

Comment: The single word is *poser*. "a person who acts in an affected manner in order to impress others." –G

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Not an exact match but you might consider [keeping up appearances](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_up_appearances).

[From dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep-up-appearances)

> to ​pretend to be ​happier, less ​poor, etc. than you really are,
>   because you do not ​want ​people to ​know how ​bad ​your ​situation
>   is:

Comment: I think this phrase usually has better regard for the person than the OP would want with the original phrase. You can keep up appearances to avoid people to feel bad for you, or you could keep up appearances in a turbulent plane flight to prevent others from getting scared, for example. Still the closest match anyway.

Comment: @Tyress I was thinking primarily of the [British sitcom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsZGHxb4caA).

Comment: A similar phrase would be "keeping up with the Joneses". From the top of the Google search:  "Keeping up with the Joneses" is an idiom in many parts of the English-speaking world referring to the comparison to one's neighbor as a benchmark for social class or the accumulation of material goods. To fail to "keep up with the Joneses" is perceived as demonstrating socio-economic or cultural inferiority.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That's already been suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 65):

The previous answers are reasonable, but rather polite. British English has a rude, but also rather funny, expression which has much the same meaning:
["all fur coat and no knickers"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_fur_coat_and_no_knickers).

The outside view (fur coat) is fine and expensive, but the wearer of the fur coat can't afford any underwear.

The expression isn't very common and perhaps slightly old fashioned but I would guess most Brits would know it.

ETA: To be fair, as pointed out below, the implication here isn't strictly financial it's more that a posh appearance hides a crude reality.

Comment: I was thinking that, but the financial element appears to be missing in dictionaries online (despite how I've heard it used).  Anyway, +1 and welcome

Comment: LOL...This British sense of humor is something else! :D

Comment: Upvoted because it's so funny... never heard that before (U.S. here).

Comment: I'd go a little further and claim it for Scotland - often aimed specifically at Edinburgh... http://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/culture/books/scottish-word-of-week-aw-fur-coat-nae-knickers-1-3285621 though it seems to have widened its sphere of influence, possibly in the wake of Billy Connolly.

Comment: I got it from my mother who was a Londoner - but it could have easily been from anywhere else prior to that. I doubt the Billy Connolly connection though - we're talking 40 years ago.

Comment: Billy Connolly was quite famous 40 years ago so it's not impossible, though I doubt he originated it.

Comment: Had I never heard this phrase before I would assume that 'no knickers' implied something other than not being able to afford any.

Comment: I've heard this expression many times in Glasgow. Billy Connolly definitely used it, but in a monologue in which he was impersonating an old aunt gossiping about a neighbour. He did not originate it.

Comment: Guessing most Brits would know it is a big assumption, but I do think most Brits would understand it.

Comment: Speaking as a Yorkshire person myself, I think you have got the meaning entirely wrong. The reason the lady in question has a fur coat is that she is - ahem - free with her affections. So to speak.

Comment: Yup, another Brit here, and I agree that the lack of underwear in this phrase has nothing to do with wealth...

Comment: "All sizzle and no steak" is the variation that I've heard.

Comment: Surely this is closer to "mutton dressed as lamb"

Answer (score 35):

Another British expression would be "Kippers and curtains" which corresponds almost directly with the Tamil phrase.  The original phrase was probably "kippers and lace curtains" dating from a time when kippers (smoked herrings) were a very cheap foodstuff and lace curtains would have been a rather expensive adornment.

It has fallen out of use a little in recent years but would still be understood by many in Britain, particularly those in England.

There is a piece [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-kip2.htm) that explains the phrase quite nicely.

Comment: I'd like to admit to being an Englishman who has never heard that phrase used.

Comment: That is a great link, @BrummiePete! It also suggests other synonymous expressions such as "***empty bellies and brass doorknobs*** and ***plus-fours and no breakfast***"!

Answer (score 25):

[**To live in genteel poverty**.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/genteel)

There are some examples under the entry for **genteel** in Oxford, [The Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/genteel), Meriam Webster.

> He lived in genteel poverty (= trying to keep the style of a high social class, but with little money). [(Oxford Dictionary)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/genteel)
>
> An elderly woman living in genteel poverty. [(Merriam Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genteel)

Comment: I can (just barely) parse this, but I've never heard it before (U.S. here), and it certainly wouldn't be a recognized idiom anywhere I've been.

Comment: As an American, I certainly wouldn't understand this. I think I'd interpret it as the opposite - a person who maintains their dignity and proper behavior despite being poor, without a sense of pretension.

Comment: Another American here, but I *do* recognize the idiom, and would interpret it as the Oxford Dictionary definition describes.

Answer (score 20):

[**all flash no cash**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=All+Flash+No+Cash)

Urban dictionary definition:

> People who spend money they do not have.

Answer (score 19):

"Hood rich" is really close to what you're looking for, but it typically describes someone who lives in the ghetto.

It's likely to be understood only in the US or in US-influenced culture.

From http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hood+Rich (cleaned up):

*Someone who buys expensive clothes, cars, and eats out at expensive restaurants, but returns home to a shack in the hood. They usually are in debt up to their ears, and they keep trying to live the affluent lifestyle until the repo man comes and tows their car.*

Comment: Can you find a reference work or a literary quote to support this?

Comment: What would be an accepted reference work or literary source for AAVE?

Comment: Hi, Myron, you could use a reference (that best matches your idea) you could find on the internet such as this one, [hood rich](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hood_rich).

Comment: Twitter, blogs, and internet comment sections are filled with vernacular and can usually be linked to.

Comment: Honestly, this one has racial overtones you might want to avoid, although it does mean just what the OP asked.

Comment: And not understood even in much of the US.

Comment: @jamesqf Potentially true. Here in Michigan, most people would understand this primarily due to the existence of the city of Detroit (not so much nowadays) and the culture therein. However, I'm not sure that southerners would understand the expression.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I'd wager dollars to doughnuts they would.

Answer (score 17):

The U.S. cowboy equivalent might be "The bigger the hat, the smaller the property—or its short-form sibling "all hat, no cattle." *The [Yale] Dictionary of Modern Proverbs* (2012) has this entry for the longer phrase:

> **The bigger the hat (The wider the brim), the smaller the property (holding, ranch, herd).** [First cited occurrence:] 1922 William MacLeod Raine, *The Fighting Edge* (New York: Grosset and Dunlap,) 135 (chapter title): "The Bigger the Hat, the Smaller the Herd," Later in the chapter:  "...[H]e knew instinctively that real riders would resent any attempt on his part to swagger as they did. A remark dropped by Blister came to mind. 'The b-bigger the hat the smaller the herd, son. Do all yore bragging with yore actions.'"

The point is that the trappings of authenticity, skill, or expertise [or in the case of the Tamil proverb, wealth] are not the same as the thing itself.

Comment: I've only encountered the "all hat, no cattle" expression in contexts where it means that someone is trying to substitute money for ability/talent/practice. They're too lazy to actually do the hard work required, but they have lots of cash, so they buy all the clothes and accessories so they can pretend. Thus, in a sense this is the opposite meaning to what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 15):

Possibly "living beyond your means", which is often used in contexts where people have become accustomed to a certain standard of living, who then lose the means to sustain that standard (e.g. losing a job, getting a divorce, moving out of your parents house).

Comment: This doesn't necessarily carry the implication of 'putting on a show'.

Comment: @DJClayworth: exactly.  It's usually used in cases where the person spending money they can't afford is doing it for their own enjoyment, *not* with the primary goal of making themselves look good.  Although given how judgy people can be, I'm sure some people live beyond their means so they don't feel out of place / left out when hanging around with their better-off friends.  (e.g. continuing to go to expensive restaurants because that's where their friends go, when they can't afford it anymore.)  So there's a bit of crossover, but the primary motivation is different.

Answer (score 13):

The person who spends everything on their home and has little left for the rest of life might be called [house poor:](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/housepoor.asp#ixzz3yeD2sE6G)

> A situation that describes a person who spends a large proportion of his or her total income on home ownership, including mortgage payments, property taxes, maintenance and utilities. House poor individuals are short of cash for discretionary items and tend to have trouble meeting other financial obligations like vehicle payments.

(Investopedia)

From a census report on home ownership:

> Since housing costs are higher in the West and Northeast, a larger percentage of owners in these two regions than in the South and Midwest were house-poor.

(Home Ownership Report, U.S. Department of Commerce, Economic and Statistics Administration, Bureau of the Census, 1991 )

Comment: This seems to be the reverse of what the question is asking.

Comment: @DJClayworth How is it reversed?  Lavish outside corresponds with high expenditures on home ownership and maintenance. Starving inside corresponds with low expenditures on discretionary items. Those who are house poor live like the poor because they spent all their money on their house.

Comment: @jejorda2: Not so, at least according to my understanding of the original.  People who are "house poor" are choosing to spend a large part of their income on something that is a) useful, and b) an appreciating asset.  That also begs the question of why a financially prudent person should even HAVE vehicle payments.  Indeed, I think that's a good example of the sort of person covered by the proverb: one who borrows money to buy a fancy new car, instead of paying cash for a cheap used one.

Comment: I took the OP to mean that the house was lavish outside, but the person was starving inside. This has been true of house poor people I have known who have no table to eat at or chair to sit in because they bought too fancy a home.

Comment: @jamesqf I agree with jejorda2.   From the outside, the people look rich.  Inside -- very little furniture, no art, scrimp on food ("cornflake eaters" was a term used in my area decades ago).  As for "something useful that is an appreciating asset": (a) a house is useful; 8,000 sq ft of house is not; (b) house as appreciating asset maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @ab2: I don't think that quite gets the flavor of the original, though.  For instance, having art or fancy furniture (bought on credit, of course) might be part of the facade the people are putting on to impress people, while they might well be eating cornflakes because they like cornflakes.  The way Sam Walton (founder of WalMart) chose to drive an older pickup, because that's what he liked.

Answer (score 12):

I think there is a cultural nuance in your proverb that may be difficult to convey perfectly, but ***[keeping up with the Joneses](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+up+with+the+Joneses)*** may suggest the idea of being keen on appearing more (especially richer) than you actually are or may afford to:

> - to have all the same things as other people to avoid looking poor or old-fashioned:
>
>   *Her only concern in life was keeping up with the Joneses.*

Comment: I'd say *keeping up with the **Joneses*** is more about *conspicuous affluence* in terms of always buying the latest new thing, with no particular implication that you might not be able to *afford* it.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I think "Jonses" here is abstract. Would you replace it with the name of the actual persons you are trying to emulate?

Comment: Yes, it is a fixed expression, changing the name to refer to people you know and you would like to be as they are would be understood within your circle, or community.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy in contrast with Josh61, I would say this is more likely to be understood if you say "keeping up with the Joneses" rather than replacing Joneses with some other family name.

Answer (score 11):

This reminds me of **Proverbs 12:9**:

> Better to be a nobody and yet have a servant than pretend to be
>   somebody and have no food.

http://biblehub.com/proverbs/12-9.htm

Comment: I'm having a hard time applying this answer to the question. If I try to apply it to the question, what I get out of it is: Better to be a nobody and yet have a servant (and I assume also having food), than pretend to be somebody (who also likely has a servant) and have no food.

Answer (score 6):

It's not in widespread use, but in Yorkshire there's a phrase "**Ten-bob millionaire**" to describe exactly such people: who put on a show of living like millionaires (very rich) in public, but in truth only own/earn a small amount of money. "Ten bob" is an old term for half a pound sterling.

Answer (score 5):

There's the phrases '[the cobbler's children are the worst shod](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_cobbler%27s_children_are_the_worst_shod)' and 'the shoemaker's children go barefoot' which have the same sense of good things outside the home, bad things inside, and it's your fault.

Comment: I don't think those have at all the same meaning.  It's not that the shoemaker is trying to put on a show of prosperity, but that he's so busy making shoes to sell that he has no time to make them for his own family.

Comment: @jamesqf: There's also the issue that if you do something all day at work, you don't really want to come home and do the same thing. I've known a number of mechanics who drive junk piles because they're too lazy to fix their own car, despite doing great work on nice cars all the time.

Answer (score 3):

***you can't judge a book by its cover***

> You can't tell what something/someone is really like just by looking at it. It might be different from what it looks.
>
> If someone says, "You can't judge a book by its cover," he/she advises you not to judge someone or something only by its appearance.
>
> People also say, "You can't tell a book by its cover."
> [elc.byu.edu](http://elc.byu.edu/elc/student/idioms/proverbs/book_cover.html)

***all that glitters is not gold***

> (*saying*) said about something that ​seems to be good on the ​surface, but might not be when you ​look at it more ​closely [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/all-that-glitters-is-not-gold)

***appearances can be deceiving***

> *Prov.* Things can look different from the way they really are. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Appearances+can+be+deceiving)

***Things aren't always what they seem***

> Just because something seems a certain way doesn’t mean it really is. [Babylon English](http://dictionary.babylon.com/things_aren%27t_always_what_they_seem/)

Comment: +1 for the basic concept ... but this can also be the reverse ... eg. a millionaire who's shabbily dressed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an exact match, but you could consider using the idiom [**house of cards**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/house+of+cards) which means:

> A flimsy structure, arrangement, or situation that is in danger of
>   collapsing or failing: '*The collapse of the rupiah ... has brought down a house of cards in overleveraged conglomerates*'.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition]

Example usage:

> They are living in a house of cards, which will surely collapse once they
>   can't pay off the debt they borrowed to maintain their luxurious lifestyle.

Comment: It works, but it's worth noting that a house of cards is any precarious situation at all.

Comment: @Casey Yes. Context should be added.

Answer (score 2):

While the phrase has  a specific religious connotation (of evil within and virtue without, where the Tamil one might have the exterior virtue of beneficence and the interior vice of waste, but maybe it's not that specific?), the structure of the concept is similar to a **whited sepulchre**:

> Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! for ye are like unto whited sepulchres, which indeed appear beautiful outward, but are within full of dead men’s bones, and of all uncleanness.

[Matthew 23:27](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/matt/23.27?lang=eng#26)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an exact match, but there's the concept of "**fake it 'til you make it**", which is about cultivating the appearance of what you want to be, even if you have nothing (skills/experience) to back it up.  The idea being that people will give you a chance if they think you're qualified.

This isn't necessarily about wealth, and it's possible that the person isn't in financial hardship.

Also related would be "**putting on airs**" (being pretentious, but again, could be about just acting superior, not necessarily wealthy, nor that the person is in "dire straits" financially)

Answer (score 1):

> Ballin' on a budget.

As coined by the hip-hop group "Nappy Roots" on their 2002 studio album *Watermelon, Chicken & Gritz*.

Answer (score 0):

A phrase "asset rich, cash poor" seems similar in it's origin. It was used for declining middle class families who owned large houses but were near bankrupt. However now that would probably be taken to mean they have low liquidity in their savings.

Comment: no connection whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Nigger Rich. 
Not a proverb but has a mocking, mean spirited tone.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nigger%20rich&page=1

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if people just make stuff up so they can put it on urbandictionary.  Like a contest in out-doing each other in being the most crude and offensive.

Comment: This is the form that I have heard before.  I suspect the the upvoted "hood rich" is a cleaned up version of this phrase.

Comment: I can't imagine an appropriate context for using this phrase (at least not one where I would willingly be present), given the emotionally fraught nature of the first word in it; but in an unsuitable context, it may very well put the speaker in jeopardy of a physical confrontation.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use "cash poor" because I may have enough of a balance on a store's credit card that I can buy something expensive (like a computer), but I may not have the cash to buy groceries. I'm also fond of "in debt up to my eyeballs" as is depicted in this commercial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0HX4a5P8eE

Answer (score 0):

"Putting up a false front" could be used in this case.  It's not as specific, but does have the same "keeping up appearances" meaning.

This [article](http://www.expressingyourselfinenglish.com/2012/02/idioms-for-putting-on-act.html) goes into some explanation of the meaning of the phrase, mostly focusing on personal appearance.  (e.g. Wearing fancy suits to make people think of you differently from how you see yourself.)

The origin is from buildings: a small / simple building with a multi-storey front wall that makes it look like a big building, but only from the front.

"Putting up a false front" (or putting *on*) can be something a family does to appear well-off when they're actually not.

Answer (score 0):

A similar phrase might be "Fur coat and no knickers"?

Comment: This answer has already been suggested by [alphabetter](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/303118/91730). Please don't post repeat answers.

Answer (score -2):

A [McMansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMansion) might fit the bill.  Generally refers to a house that looks luxurious from the outside but may in reality be poorly constructed.  Also usually implies that it is somewhat out of place in its neighborhood.

Comment: Out of place in the neighborhood?  We used to use them specifically to describe the neighborhoods of cookie-cutter massive houses that would pop up almost one on top of each other (eg, a 5k sq.ft house ... on 1/4 of an acre).    Often in a faux-gated community.  (there'd be a fence around it, and maybe something that looked like a guardhouse, but no actual guards).  When I was in Kentucky, they referred to them as a 'doctor's ghetto'.

Comment: @Joe - I was quoting the linked Wikipedia article on that one.  Apparently usage varies by region.

Comment: My understanding of "McMansion" (from having a bunch of them a few blocks away) is that it is one of dozens of identical "cookie cutter" monstrosities in a wannabe neighborhood.  Slightly less ostentatious is the "garage-mahal", a gigantic garage taking up most of the front yard and concealing most of the house behind it.

Comment: It is true that a McMansion is often poorly constructed, having been built by the same people who do cookie-cutter tract homes.  But the interior is usually faux-luxurious, with hardwood floors, marble countertops and the like.

Comment: @Joe: Re "...on 1/4 of an acre", do your local developers really put their McMansions on lots THAT big?

Comment: +1. You can indulge in the McMansion experience that Darrel Hoffman has in mind in much of southwest Houston, where, in neighborhoods that once were composed almost exclusively of one-story ranch-style houses, every fifth or sixth house today is an out-of-scale monstrosity that seems to consist mainly of an enclosed two-or three-story atrium, since the rebuilders couldn't figure out anything else to do with all the additional space they insisted on enclosing.

Comment: "McMansion" has nothing to do with the build quality or owners within the residence, it simply refers to the fact that there are many homes which look remarkably similar, stacked next to each other in a neighborhood. It also indicates that the homes are built quickly, as if by a "fast food" company.

Comment: @JoeBlow: As I understand it, a McMansion will be big, but without the fancy hardwood furniture and so on that you'd find in a proper mansion.  Like a regular house scaled up, in some ways.  Whoever wrote the wiki entry was probably thinking along those lines.  There can be whole subdivisions of McMansions like Joe was talking about, but individual McMansions can also be found mixed in with nice old houses in an already-built-up good part of town, esp. in older cities (by north american standards).

Comment: the OP wants "lavish outside but starving inside".  a McMansion IS EXPENSIVE, it very much means "rich but no taste".  it simply does not mean "lavish outside but starving inside".  it more means "very fat and very rich with no taste"

Comment: The OP also did say "*Any suggestions, even if they don't convey the entire meaning?*"  So this is at least partly related.

Comment: @Joe Blow: There's also a bit of... well, I don't know exactly what to call it, maybe faux rich?  As for instance you might see an actual rich person build a similar house (with better-quality construction), but on an estate of many acres, instead of jammed cheek-to-jowl on lots of a few thousand square feet.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Look, I don't know why you seem to have some personal vendetta against this answer.  I've provided source to back it up, and several other people have expressed support for it, so obviously there are other people who use the term in this manner.  Frankly, you're starting to come off as a little bit hostile and abusive here.  Language usage is subjective and varies by region and culture.  Not every word means the same thing to all people.  I'd kindly suggest you just back away and let it go.  Nothing matters that much.

Comment: Huh?  All I said was my comment 5 comments above ("the OP wants...").  In any event, this answer is **far better than** the bizarre-upvoted highest vote answer.

Comment: Darrel and @Joe: I think at this point the comments are just replying to other comments and getting off the topic of whether your answer is a good fit for the question. Sorry for spamming your notification box! I think JoeBlow's "rich but no taste" is the best way to put the connotations this word has for me. It doesn't really have the "keeping up appearances" / "putting up a false front" connotation. Most people can recognize a McMansion for what it is, so it's not just owning a McMansion but going around bragging about it's square footage and number of rooms without letting on that it sucks.

Comment: I'm fascinated by Peter Cordes's suggestion that _McMansion_ might originally have referred to cookie-cutter, second-rate, mansion-size new homes that might fill a whole subdivision. The description makes a lot of sense—and yet (as I noted earlier) the term as used in Houston referred to big houses on small lots that were set among utterly different-looking ranch-style houses and yet looked nothing like the mansions in truly ritzy older neighborhoods like River Oaks and Sunset. Evidently, people's notions of what the term connotes are tied to different usage in different cities and regions.

Answer (score -2):

There is a similar expression that I have heard Irish people use. If someone is described as a "street angel" that means that they are very well behaved in public but maybe less so at home.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. that is nice your answer, but could you please expand your question a little more, and if it is possible for you, add a link to support your answer. Thank