# A phrase comparable to 'In the house of the blacksmith, wooden knives'

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation

In Spanish, we have a phrase..

> *En casa de herrero, cuchillos de palo.*

Literally,

> In the house of the blacksmith, wooden knives.

The meaning is probably clear, but some examples:

- A math teacher whose children cannot add.
- A software engineer who is still using Windows 95 at home.
- ...a country which supposedly leads the world in technology and
  industry,  yet is still incapable of providing the most basic of manufactured goods needed  to confront a major crisis and [must import them.](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2020/03/distributors-are-racing-to-import-n95-masks-from-china.html)

Is there a comparable expression or phrase in English that describes this situation?

Comment: At this very moment in NYC, Doctors and Nurses are being asked to use _diapers and scarves_ as face masks.

Comment: @Peter Shor I had been hoping to leave the Q open a little longer...and the dupe would have been impossible to find unless possibly you remembered it.

Comment: [Another duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303080/is-there-a-similar-english-phrase-for-this-tamil-proverb-lavish-outside-home/303177#303177), with "the cobbler's children are the worst shod," which is essentially the same idiom as "the shoemaker's children go barefoot."

Comment: @PeterShor I had almost included the equivalent of that in the Q ["_en casa de Zapatero andan descalzos_"], but my native-speaker wife said it was probably not as common in Latin America as the other expression.

Comment: The car designer works from home.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Especially this week? month?....year?

Comment: It reminds me of the barefoot cobbler's son. He who makes all the shoes end up making none for his own kids. A lesson in priorities for busy people. Edit: Yes, I just saw the other comment as I added this one.

Comment: "The editer's posts are ridled with tipos." That certainly applies to me.